# Clousure of connected set is connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I know closure of connected set in a topological space must be connected as well. However, I can't understand why this counterexample fails.
Take $X=[0,2)\cup\{3\}, B_2(1)=(0,2)$ which is connected. Now take the closed ball $C_2(1)=[0,2)\cup \{3\}$ which is clearly not connected. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the closure of $(0,2)$ in $[0,2)\cup\{3\}$ is $[0,2)$, not $[0,2)\cup\{3\}$. The closure of an open ball is not always the corresponding closed ball.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, the closure of the open ball $ B_2(1) $ is not the closed ball $ C_2(1)$. This is because we have $ (B_{1/2}(3) \cap X)  \cap B_2(1) = \varnothing $ and this shows that $ 3 $ is not an adherent point of $ B_{2}(1) $ in $ X $.